# how to make categories linkable to their entries? (i.e., link_ to)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to figure out how to make my categories linkable to their entries.

I have only one model, `Entry` which has scrapped data from Reddit (title, link, and category)

Now have the data displayed on the `index.html.erb` page alongside with the category in a sidebar ... but it's not linked.

How do I make it linkable to the entries it came from?

The most I've come up with which is in the `index.html.erb` as well but it trails off because I'm not sure how to call the specific entry that I'm clicking on the column for ... ie, if I click on jokes, I want to get all entries that have that specific category show up ...

Here's the incomplete link_to `<p><%= link_to '@lala.join(" ")', :action %></p>`

Do I put in the parameter of [:category] in the path above?

**Entries Controller**

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController


def index
  @entries = Entry.all
  @lala = @entries.select(:category).map(&:category).uniq
  #@entries = Entry.all.group_by{ |entry| entry.category }

end

def scrape

    RedditScrapper.scrape

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to entries_url, notice: 'Entries were successfully scraped.' }
      format.json { entriesArray.to_json }
    end
  end

end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card-columns">
            <% @entries.reverse.each do |entry| %>
                <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <p class="card-title"><b><%= entry.title %></b></p>
                    <p class="card-text"><%= entry.link %></p>
                    <p class="card-type"><%= cat(entry.category) %></p>
            </div>
        </div>
   <% end %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <p><%= link_to '@lala.join(" ")', :action %></p>
</div>

</div>
```

**scraper**

```
require 'open-uri'

module RedditScrapper
  def self.scrape
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.reddit.com/"))

    entries = doc.css('.entry')
    entries.each do |entry|
      title = entry.css('p.title > a').text
      link = entry.css('p.title > a')[0]['href']
      category = entry.css('p.tagline > a.subreddit')[0]['href']
      Entry.create!(title: title, link: link, category: category )
    end
  end

end
```

**Entry model**

```
class Entry < ApplicationRecord

    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :link, presence: true
    validates :category, presence: true

end
```

**routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    #root 'entry#scrape_reddit'
    root 'entries#index'
    resources :entries
    #get '/new_entries', to: 'entries#scrape', as: 'scrape'
end
```